# Different DB schemas AWS Database Migration Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, database-migration, aws-dms

I have two Databases, one is target and other is source. The schema and table structures of DBs are entirely different. I want to migrate all data from source to target DB using AWS DMS. Is there a way to map different columns of source DB tables to different columns in target DB tables.

I will provide more details if asked.

I want to get solution or a workaround in using AWS DMS.